# Compare column value with result from stored procedure 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need compare in the where if the property `boleta.c_Fk_CodPeriodo` is equal to return value of SP `dbo.paBltPeriodoBuscarUnico3 @fecha`. The SP return value like '1011', '0711', etc..

```
SELECT 
   localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta
FROM 
   Blt_Boleta as boleta, Fnc_Localizacion as localizacion
WHERE 
   boleta.c_Pk_IdBoleta = localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta 
   AND localizacion.si_CodAsa = @id_Asa 
   AND  boleta.c_Fk_CodPeriodo = exec  dbo.paBltPeriodoBuscarUnico3 @fecha
```

The problem in exec says, syntax error in exec... so

How can I do this??

Comment: What do you mean the stored procedure return value is `0711`? The return value can only be an integer, not a string. Do you mean that it returns a scalar result set with a string?

Comment: Is the value returned from the stored procedure by a resultset or through the `RETURN` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @output AS varchar(4);
exec @output = dbo.paBltPeriodoBuscarUnico3 @fecha;

 SELECT 
                         localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta
                    FROM 
                         Blt_Boleta as boleta, Fnc_Localizacion as localizacion
                    WHERE 
                         boleta.c_Pk_IdBoleta = localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta 
                         AND localizacion.si_CodAsa = @id_Asa 
                         AND  boleta.c_Fk_CodPeriodo = @output
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to call the stored procedure first and assign the result to a variable then use the variable in the query.

You can't use stored procedures like that.